# Why am I getting "invalid program counter value" in mars?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to convert hexadecimal to an integer, but I keep getting this error.

The error is: Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000

I am using this as a guide https://github.com/exercism/mips/blob/master/exercises/hexadecimal/example.mips

```
.data
getHex: .asciiz "Enter 32-bit hex: "
userInput: .space 8
hexvals: .word 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15


.text
li $v0, 4 # put 4 in register $v0 in order to print whats in the address of $a0
la $a0, getHex # put the address of label getHex in $a0 in order for string with null to be printed
syscall

li $v0, 8
la $a0, userInput
li $a1, 9
syscall


hex_convert:
        li      $v0, 0                  # Reset accumulator to 0.
        la      $t0, hexvals           # Load address of lookup into register.
loop:
        lb      $t1, 0($a0)             # Load a character,
        beq     $t1, $zero, end         # if it is null then return.
        sll     $v0, $v0, 4             # Otherwise first shift accumulator by 4 to multiply by 16.
        addi    $t2, $t1, -48           # Then find the offset of the char from '0'
        sll     $t2, $t2, 2             # in bytes,
        addu    $t2, $t2, $t0           # use it to calcute address in lookup,
        lw      $t3, 0($t2)             # retrieve its integer value,
        addu    $v0, $v0, $t3           # and add that to the accumulator.
        addi    $a0, $a0, 1             # Finally, increment the pointer
        j       loop                    # and loop.

end:
        jr $ra
```

Comment: You're missing a `main` label. After `.text` you should have the two lines `.globl main` and `main:`.

Comment: @Michael Alright, I think I put them in the right spot but I am still getting an error.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. It helped me fix it by putting the .globl part (the stuff with hex_convert and loop) above the getHex and userInput portion. I honestly do not understand why that is what was messing it up. I am new to assembly. I am taking computer architecture in university and feel pretty lost. Cheers!

Comment: MARS doesn't use the `main` label, it always starts at the top even if you have a `main` elsewhere that is `.globl`. QtSpim honors your `main`, wherever it is, though.

Comment: You need to call your function, using `jal`.  And finish your main with a syscall #10 after calling your function.  Right now, you're letting the main simply fall into the function.  Not good: the return at the end has no where to go back to.  You'll see that `$ra` has 0 in it.